# Como contar repetições em um intervalo usando length(which()) no R

Tags: r

Crio o data frame chamado `producao`:

```
producao<-data.frame(aluno = c("Pedro", "Joao", "Marcio", "Pedro", "Joao", "Pedro", "Marcio", "Marcio", "Marcio"),
                     qualis = c("A1", "B2", "A1", "B2", "NP", "C", "A2", "A1", "B2"))

producao

> producao
   aluno qualis
1  Pedro     A1
2   Joao     B2
3 Marcio     A1
4  Pedro     B2
5   Joao     NP
6  Pedro      C
7 Marcio     A2
8 Marcio     A1
9 Marcio     B2
```

Gostaria de saber como calcular a quantidade de repetições de um determinado termo na coluna "qualis".
Estou particularmente interessado em saber como fazer isso com a função `length()` combinada com `which()`.

Se eu quiser saber quantos "A1", eu faço:

```
length(which(producao$qualis == "A1"))

[1] 3
```

Mas, e se eu quiser saber quantos registros há no intervalo de "A1" até "A2"?

Consigo fazer isso usando `%in%`:

```
length(which(producao$qualis %in% c("A1", "A2")))

[1] 4
```

Com poucos levels fica simples usar a vírgula, mas e se eu tiver muitos "levels" na variável "qualis"?

Fica inconveniente ficar digitando todos os levels que quero considerar.

Daí eu queria tentar um comando que pudesse capturar um **intervalo**

Imaginei que `:` funcionaria; mas não deu certo

```
length(which(producao$qualis %in% c("A1":"A2")))

Error in "A1":"A2" : Argumento NA/NaN
Além disso: Warning messages:
1: In producao$qualis %in% c("A1":"A2") : NAs introduzidos por coerção
2: In producao$qualis %in% c("A1":"A2") : NAs introduzidos por coerção
```

**EXEMPLO DE VETOR LONGO**

```
exemplo<- factor (c(
  "B1",
  "B4",
  "NP",
  "A3",
  "B4",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B4",
  "B2",
  "A3",
  "A1",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B4",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "B3",
  "B1",
  "A2",
  "B3",
  "A3",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B3",
  "A3",
  "A4",
  "A4",
  "B3",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "A1",
  "NP",
  "NP",
  "A2",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "B1",
  "B3",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "C",
  "NP",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "A3",
  "A1",
  "A4",
  "C",
  "A1",
  "A2",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "A2",
  "A3",
  "B4",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "NP",
  "C",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "B4",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B3",
  "B1",
  "B4",
  "B1",
  "A4",
  "A4",
  "A4",
  "B3",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "NP",
  "B2",
  "B2",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A1",
  "A1",
  "B4",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "C",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B3",
  "B2",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "B2",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "A3",
  "NP",
  "A3",
  "A4",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B3",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A2",
  "C",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "A1",
  "A1",
  "A1",
  "A4",
  "A1",
  "B4",
  "NP",
  "B2",
  "C",
  "C",
  "C",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "A4",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "C",
  "A4",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "C",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A4",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "B2",
  "NP",
  "NP",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "NP",
  "A2",
  "NP",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "C",
  "C",
  "A2",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "C",
  "A4",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "A2",
  "A2",
  "A2",
  "B2",
  "NP",
  "C",
  "A1",
  "B2",
  "B3",
  "B3",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B3",
  "B2",
  "A2",
  "A1",
  "B1",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "B3",
  "A4",
  "B1",
  "A1",
  "A2",
  "B3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A2",
  "NP",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B2",
  "A2",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "A2",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A4",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A4",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "B3",
  "A3",
  "NP",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "B3",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "NP",
  "A4",
  "A3",
  "B3",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "A3",
  "A2",
  "B1",
  "A3",
  "B2",
  "A4",
  "A3",
  "B1",
  "NP",
  "B1",
  "A3"),
  levels = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C", "NP"))

head(exemplo)

[1] B1 B4 NP A3 B4 B1
Levels: A1 A2 A3 A4 B1 B2 B3 B4 C NP
```

Comment: A letra é sempre a mesma, só os números é que variam? Por exemplo, `paste0("A", 2:9)` dá um vetor de `"A2"` até `"A9"`.

Comment: Olá Rui Barradas.
São 10 níveis: "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "C", "NP"
Acrescentei um vetor de exemplo, com o nome ```exemplo``` já como factor.

O que gostaria de saberé como contar quantos registros há entre A1 até A4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A1:A2` não irá funcionar porque está lidando com string de texto. Como sugerido por @rui-barradas nos comentários, pode montar a sequência usando `paste`:

```
length(which(exemplo %in% paste0("A", 1:4)))
#> [1] 134
```

Outra opção é utilizar uma expressão regular indicando a letra e a faixa de dígitos desejada:

```
length(grep("A[1-4]", exemplo))
#> [1] 134
```

Ou simplesmente `"A"` se quiser todos os qualis A, independente da numeração. Se quer pegar faixas com mais de uma letra (p.e., todos os qualis que possuem fator de impacto):

```
length(grep("A|B[1-2]", exemplo))
#> [1] 281
```

Answer (score 2):

Talvez a seguinte função possa resolver o problema.
Aceita duas strings no formato da pergunta e cria um vetor com os números em sequência.

```
rangeAlphanum <- function(x, y){
  xchar <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[[:digit:]]+"))
  xnum <- unlist(strsplit(x, "[^[:digit:]]"))
  ynum <- unlist(strsplit(y, "[^[:digit:]]"))
  xnum <- as.integer(xnum[xnum != ""])
  ynum <- as.integer(ynum[ynum != ""])
  paste0(xchar, xnum:ynum)
}

rangeAlphanum("A1", "A4")
#[1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4"
```

Aplicando a função ao vetor `exemplo`, primeiro com a soma de um vetor lógico, uma vez que `FALSE/TRUE` é codificado como `0/1`, e depois com `length(which(.))`, tal como pedido:

```
sum(exemplo %in% rangeAlphanum("A1", "A4"))
#[1] 134

length(which(exemplo %in% rangeAlphanum("A1", "A4")))
#[1] 134
```